# atof() not able to read 'e' in 8e-6

Tags: atof

I am trying to read type `double` values from a `char buffer` word by word. In the file I have some values like `0.032 0.1234 8e-6 4e-3` etc. Here is my code which is using `atof()` function to convert word (stored in array '`s`') to a double value `num` :

```
char s[50];
double num;
while(getline(str, line))
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    while(line[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(line[i] != ' ')
        {
            s[j] = line[i];
            //cout << s[j];   <-- output of s[j] shows correct values (reading 'e' correctly)
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            num = atof(s);
            cout << num << " ";
            j=0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Whenever numbers which include 'e' in them (like 8e-6) comes, atof() function just returns 0 for them. Output for above example values comes out to be `0.032 0.1234 0 0`.

I tried to check with a demo array and there atof() worked fine.

```
char t[10];
    t[0] = '8';
    t[1] = 'e';
    t[2] = '-';
    t[3] = '5';
    t[4] = '\0';

    double td = atof(t);
    cout << "td = " << td << endl;
```

Here the output is `td = 8e-05`
I have included both `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: What answer are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting `0.032 0.1234 8e-06 4e-03`.

Comment: Please learn how to debug. It's simple and is the most important skill you need right now.

Comment: My curiosity is killing me. [**Why not just do this**](http://ideone.com/4OYZ9g) ? (I'm relying on this question being tagged C++, which it should *not* be if it is tagged C, and vice-versa).

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks, it works now.

Comment: Please update your question to show us your actual code. You define `s` and then refer to `str`, which is not defined. Show us a complete program that exhibits the problem, including any required `#include` directives and a definition of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass into function `atof()` only a correct representaton of `double`, otherwise the return value is 0.

If you will check a very simple code
    char p[] = "6e-5";
    double a = atof(p);
you will see that it is working.

It means that you have a problem not with `6e-5` number iself, but with a wrong representation of you string `s`.